# java - Can only send file once

Tags: java, networking

I have a gui where I click the send button on one pc and the receive button on another pc and it sends the file. The problem is that I can only send the file once and then I have to restart the app.

The reasons it gives for failing are these:
"Socket is closed" on the sending pc, although I dont see why it would say that.
"ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" on the receiving pc.

I've got these two methods which I use for sending the data:

```
public void StreamIn() throws Exception {      //FOR RECEIVING FILES

    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[size];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVE);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    current = bytesRead;

    do {
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
        if (bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead > -1);

    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
    bos.flush();

    if (fos != null) fos.close();
    if (bos != null) bos.close();
}

public void StreamOut() throws Exception {      //FOR SENDING FILES

    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os = sock.getOutputStream();

    os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();

    if (bis != null) bis.close();
    if (os != null) os.close();
}
```

For some reason the OutputStream wont write a second time, although I close and recreate them before trying to send another file. I dont see why the sending pc would say the socket is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You're closing the socket after sending one file. If you want to send another file, open another socket.

NB your copy loop is correct in `StreamIn()` but incorrect in `StreamOut().` You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer, and you're also assuming that `mybytearray` is as large as the file, and you are therefore also assuming that the file size fits into an `int.`

The canonical way to copy streams in Java is:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this in both methods.

Also `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Also `StreamOut()` is missing a declaration for `mybytearray.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what is "buffer" in this code? And also, I cant read without finally closing the outputstream. Does this close the socket as well?

Comment: I see it does close the socket as well, solution is to use Socket.shutdownOutput()

Comment: **edit** not really a solution: you can't reuse the outputstream after that